# Adding a html value to the attribute of an image

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue with this.. is the value gets added but only the first `h2` tag. What am I missing?

**Thanks**

**My goal** is to grab the value of the `h2` tag and add the value to the image as an `alt` and `title` tag.

Below is my HTML and JS. Here is my [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/jv7M7/).

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <img title="Product" src="/img.jpg" />
    <h2>Blue</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img title="Product" src="/img.jpg" />
    <h2>Red</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img title="Product" src="/img.jpg" />
    <h2>Yellow</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

​

**JS**

```
var imageID = $('.list').find('h2').html();

$("img").attr('title', imageID + ' Product');​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".list img").each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).siblings("h2").text();
    $(this).prop("alt", txt).prop("title", txt + " Product");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jv7M7/3/) - *use Firebug or similar to review*

Comment: This worked. However, how can I add the `h2` value to the `title` attribute & `alt` and also append custom text to the end of the `title` attribute on the image? Similar to how i originally had it.. `$("img").attr('title', imageID + ' Product');​`

Comment: Just set the `title` parameter exactly the same way as you have set the `alt` - see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$("img").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('title', $(this).closest("li").find("h2").text()+ ' Product');​
})
```